# Outlook.exe command line multiple attachments is it possible?

Tags: outlook, command-line-arguments, email-attachments

I want create outlook emails with two attachments !
I can't attach two files (pdf, doc, etc) in command line with outlook.exe
command line Any solutions ?

I tried outlook.exe /a but it accepts only one file to attach !

Answer (score 1):

No, `/a` command line parameter can only specify a single file for Outlook - it won't let you pass a list of files, and you cannot have multiple `/a` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Or we only have the possibility to attach only one single file with outlook.exe ?

Yes, the `/a` switch is limited to a single attachment. You can't attach multiple files using the `/a` command line switch.

As a possible workaround you may create a script which can process multiple command line parameters for attaching to a new Outlook item:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set App = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

If Err <> 0 Then Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set AppItem = App.CreateItem(0)

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 then
  For FileName = 0 to (WScript.Arguments.Count - 1)
    AppItem.Attachments.Add WScript.Arguments(FileName)
  Next
  AppItem.Display
End If

Set App = Nothing
Set AppItem = Nothing
```

You can save this code in the `.vbs` file (VBScript) and run it when you need to attach multiple files.